Configure custom FHIR profile for Google Healthcare API
I am trying to setup a Google Healthcare FHIR data store using the International Patient Summary (IPS) FHIR IG. I have done the following:

downloaded the json specification files and unzipped it
deleted spec.internals file from the definitions.json
compiled a bundle using the bundler Python tool
uploaded the resulting bundle.json to a bucket associated with the dataset
trying to create a dataset with this custom IG, which seems to work ok because I can now select the IPS as a customer IG 

But when I try to complete the data store creation, I get an error in the Google Cloud console

I have filed this issue for feedback. Does anyone have a hint/pointer as to how to validate the bundle?

I think the problem is with certain StructuredDefinitions in the package above that are not for resources (e.g. there are SDs for data types like Ranges). SDs are linked to the ImplementationGuide resource via the ImplementationGuide.global array, which takes in FHIR ResourceTypes in its type field, so SDs not meant for a type of resource won't be associated with one.
That being said, do you know if for the IPS IG package, the data type SDs are meant for specific resource types, or are meant to be applied globally to all resources?

thanks for this @brian s. I have tried removing the generic StructureDefinitions, but if I do so I get an error with the bundler, like zKeyError: StructureDefinition/SimpleQuantity-uv-ips. As far as I understand it, these general StructureDefinitions are referenced in the profiled ResourceTypes. I don't have a full grasps of FHIR and the specific IPS Implentation how global SDs work (although I do understand your point).

No worries, so there's a been a new release of the tool in the Github repo, think it now helps skip those StructureDefs in bundling the IG without removing them from the folder (I think you still need to have those SDs in the bundle, just not in the IG's global array, so this helps with that). Give it a try now :)

Whoohoo, happy, happy, joy, joy ... thanks @brian s. That did the trick!

Glad it worked!
